# Installing List Compenent on Sharepoint Server

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-dynamics-crm

I added the Sharepoint site to the 'Document Management' section in CRM with the List Components checked and it added it with no problem. Also when I navigate to the 'Documents' section under an account it shows up with the format of the List components. However, if i click on 'New' or 'Actions' I get the following error message:

```
An Error has occured in the script on this page.
Error: Access is denied
URL: https://*serveraddress*/crmgrid/scripts/crmmenu.htc
Do you want to continue running scripts on this page?
```

I have ran the power script which added the MIME .htc extention to IIS.

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to stem from the fact that the SharePoint connection is in an iFrame and it is trying to call the document object of the parent window somewhere.  IE will prevent this to protect against cross-site scripting.  You can test this by opening the address of the iFrame in a separate browser window.  Here, the New and Action menus should work fine.

One solution is to add both sites to your trusted sites zone in Internet Options and enable "Allow script-initiated windows without size or position constraints."